# Python how to use a method in a list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a method to remove punctuation from every word in an array of words and I want to use it a list comprehension. All I can think of with my basic Python knowledge is:

```
def remove_punctuation(sentence: str) -> str:
    return sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

def letters_only(astr):
return astr.isalpha()

def clean_text(docs):
    cleaned_docs = []
    for doc in docs:
        cleaned_docs.append(' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(remove_punctuation(word.lower()))
                         for word in doc.split()
                         if letters_only(word)
                         and remove_punctuation(word) not in all_names
                         and remove_punctuation(word) not in all_names_lower]))
    return cleaned_docs
```

As you can see I am using the"remove_punctuation" method in many place. Is there any way to use if only once or more efficiently?

Thanks!

*letters_only - it is from some tutorial and unfortunatelly it sees word "best!" with exclamation mark at the end and removes the word - bu I am trying to make it remove only exclamation mark.

Comment: You can remove punctuation before list comprehension?

Comment: There are hacks to avoid calling functions twice in a list comprehension by wrapping their return value in a container and iterating over it, but it looks really ugly. Your list comprehension is too long anyways. Write a for loop, imo. edit: And in your specific case, what @AnkitJaiswal said.

Comment: Also, following the naming convention, checking in all_names and all_names_lower seems redundant.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Op condition is strange, but `letters_only` is applied to the word *with* punctuation, so, in the general case, the OP cannot simply `map(remove_punctuation, doc.split())` and then apply that condition. Still: the names here seem to imply the whole thing does not really do much...

Comment: Sorry I did not post letters_only code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provided the definitions for `letters_only` and `remove_punctuation` we can now say that your code is equivalent to:

```
[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())
                         for word in doc.split()
                         if letters_only(word) and word.lower() not in all_names_lower]
```

So all the calls to `remove_punctuation` are useless, because they are done only if `letters_only(word)` which means `word` does not have any punctuation.

---

Not really. The best you can do is `zip` together the original list with a generator that removes punctuation:

```
original_words = doc.split()
no_punct_words = map(remove_punctuation, original_words)

cleaned_docs.append(' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(no_punct_word.lower())
                         for word, no_punct_word in zip(original_words, no_punct_words) if letters_only(word)
                         and no_punct_word not in all_names
                         and no_punct_word not in all_names_lower]))
```

Anyway your conditions do not make much sense. If the `if letters_only(word)` condition is true I'd expect `remove_punctuation` to do nothing to `word` and so you could remove it.

Also: the two conditions:

```
no_punct_word not in all_names and no_punct_word not in all_names_lower
```

Could probably become just:

```
no_punct_word.lower() not in all_names_lower
```

---

As an aside: if the conditions you want to apply should always be applied to `remove_punctuation(word)` then you can do better: you can just `map` that function:

```
no_punct_words = map(remove_punctuation, doc.split())
# ...
[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())
                         for word in no_punct_words if letters_only(word)
                         and word.lower() not in all_names_lower]
```

And maybe you can do the same with `.lower()`:

```
lower_no_punct_words = map(str.lower, map(remove_punctuation, doc.split()))
# ...
[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
                         for word in lower_no_punct_words if letters_only(word)
                         and word not in all_names_lower]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess the intention (the code seems to have few bugs), I'd say you should be good with something like the below. Note the laziness of the whole thing, it should make the code less greedy on memory consumption.

```
def normalized_words_of(doc):
    for word in doc.split():
        if letters_only(word):
            yield remove_punctuation(word.lower())

def clean_text(docs):
    for doc in docs:
        yield ' '.join(word for word in normalized_words_of(doc) if word not in all_names_lower)

print(list(clean_text(['hi there, you', 'good bye - till next time'])))
```